# How can I change A-pose to T-pose without destroying the actions?

Tags: rigging, armature

Is it possible without retargeting?

I have mocap actions already mapped to a rig I inherited, but the rest pose is in A-pose and it is rotated in a weird way.

How can I change to a proper T-pose (I need it to be a T-pose further down the pipeline) and keep all actions from being messed up in the process?

Thanks, and will appreciate any pointers

Using Blender 4.0.2

Comment: It is not possible without retargting, but it is the simplest retargeting job imaginable.  If only upper arm rotation changes, then only upper arm needs to be retargeted.  You can simply copy rotation, world->world, onto T-pose upper arms and bake the action (visual keying, pose, selected bones) onto those two bones; remove copy rotation constraints when done.

Comment: @nathan Thanks! I went on retargeting the whole thing. Too many various and complex actions. Figured out a way that fits my workflow. Involves Expy and Rokoko btw. Cheers!